# How to get parent window scrollTop in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside the iframe scope, this works in other browsers:

```
$(parent.document.documentElement).scrollTop()
```

In Chrome it returns zero (always). Anyone knows the catch?

In backstage: I need to center modal dialog on screen (fixed position), but I cannot set correct margin top without parent window scrollTop.

Comment: Sounds like this could be restricted due to iframe cross-domain security issues...I may be wrong

Comment: Both are on same domain. Even if they are not, don't think parent window scrollTop would be restricted value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome, document.documentElement.scrollTop is always 0. The actual scroll value is in document.body. Discussed here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157855

You should use:

```
var parentScrollTop = $(parent.document.documentElement).scrollTop() || $(parent.document.body).scrollTop();
```